# Use the onstatechange: function from the jQuery Slider Plugin in order to bind slider to select element (as in the jQueryUI Demo)

Tags: jquery-ui, bind, uislider, html-select

I am trying to modify the function given in the [jQuery UI demos](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#hotelrooms) for binding a slider to an existing select element in order to work with the [jQuery Slider Plugin](http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/).  The function should allow the user to change the value to either the slider or select element and it automatically updates the other element.

I've modified the function for the plugin to update the Slider when the value of the Select element changes, but I don't know how to modify the function so that the Select element is updated when the value of the Slider changes.

**UPDATE -** The plugin documentation has an 'onstatechange function()' which fires when the slider change state, but I'm not sure how to modify the code to meet my needs. The sample code given is: `onstatechange: function( value ){console.dir( this ); }`, and a fiddle using the onStateChange: function is posted here: http://jsfiddle.net/v3gUg/18

*HTML & JS*

```
<select name="SliderSelect" id="SliderSelect">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
<div class="layout">      
    <div class="layout-slider">
      <input id="Slider" type="slider" name="area"  value="3"/>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function () {
        var select = $("#SliderSelect");
        jQuery("#Slider").slider({ 
            from: 1, 
            to: 5, 
            scale: ['Dislike','','','', 'Love'], 
            limits: false, 
            step: 1, 
            dimension: '',
            skin: "classic"
        }); 
        $("#SliderSelect").change(function () {
            jQuery("#Slider").slider("value", this.selectedIndex + 1);
        });
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

*Function used in the jQuery UI Demo*

```
$(function () {
    var select = $("#minbeds");
    var slider = $("<div id='slider'></div>").insertAfter(select).slider({
        min: 1,
        max: 6,
        range: "min",
        value: select[0].selectedIndex + 1,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            select[0].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
        }
    });
    $("#minbeds").change(function () {
        slider.slider("value", this.selectedIndex + 1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try specifying a function to respond to slider changes as the `change` attribute?

```
jQuery("#Slider").slider({ 
        from: 1, 
        to: 5, 
        scale: ['Dislike','','','', 'Love'], 
        limits: false, 
        step: 1, 
        dimension: '',
        skin: "classic"
        // add this
        change: function( event, ui ) {  
             //... add your response code here}
        }
    });
```

Comment: I've tried using the format you suggested, as well as "$("#SliderC").change(function (event, ui) {", but it doesn't seem to work with the plugin

Comment: The plugin has an 'onstatechange: function' which I think may be the way to go, but I'm not quite sure how to apply it

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/gradualstudent/e4kU3/2/    I'm not a programming expert, so forgive me if I'm misreading the question.  The issue is to get the slider to change the drop down and vice versa?    The slider width in the fiddle is not quite right.. move the slider just a tiny fraction from the left hand side.

Comment: The fiddle you posted seems to have a similar issue - When you change the select element the slider is updated, but it's not working in reverse - when the slider changes the select element isn't changing :-(

Comment: Aha, but it is.  The issue is the width of the slider is wrong -- 1 to 5 takes up just 40 pixels or so while the slider is the whole width of the screen.  Try moving the slider in a tiny area to the left most end.

Comment: Try this, http://jsfiddle.net/gradualstudent/e4kU3/3/.  Here just changed `from/to` to `min/max` in the options.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26313/discussion-between-user645715-and-chaya-cooper)

Comment: I'm sorry that I wasn't available last night, but I'm free to chat today if you're available

Comment: Unfortunately the slider in the 2nd fiddle doesn't move :-( I see what you're talking about with the 1rst fiddle, but I don't believe that the issue is the width because the 'step' option controls the increments and the slider width is then evenly divided amongst the increments. The plugin adds tick marks at each increment, so I created a fiddle which links to the plugin and using your script http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/v3gUg/23/. I found a fiddle which uses the onStateChange: function, which may help http://jsfiddle.net/v3gUg/18/

Comment: Hm, puzzling, as the fiddle seems to work.  I'm wondering if it's the browser, or the entire link didn't transfer.    http://jsfiddle.net/gradualstudent/e4kU3/3/

Comment: I hadn't thought to check until you mentioned it, but the issue was that the plugin's resources hadn't been transferred to your fiddle. It took me a little while to get the hang of those ;-) I created a new fiddle with your code together with the resources (Most of them are under 'External Resources' in the left menu, and in the CSS in the top right section. I also had to include some of it in the html - which is generally a no-no in fiddles - because for some reason they didn't work as 'External Resources' http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/v3gUg/33/

Comment: It turns out that the plugin requires using an 'onstatechange' function, and thanks to the awesome SO community I finally got that puppy working :-D http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/v3gUg/30/

Answer (score 0):

You can use onstatechange in place of the callback. The effect is that your function is fired as the slider is moving and it won't wait for a mouse up event

```
 jQuery("#Slider").slider({
                from: 0, 
                to: max_slider_val, 
                step: 1, 
                smooth: true, 
                round: 0, 
                dimension: "&nbsp;", 
                skin: "plastic", 
                onstatechange: function( myvalue ){ 
                  console.log(myvalue);
                  } });
```